# Virtual ListView with groups

Tags: listview, delphi

Virtual ListView doesn't support groups cause its underlying windows control doesn't support them either. I need both "virtuality" and grouping. What is the best approach for creating such functionality? VirtualTreeView?

Comment: You might take a look at TVirtualStringTree, see e,g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093145/multiple-expanding-nodes-in-virtual-treeview-possible

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Buy the way is it possible to show filters in its header? There is no such functionality in ListView, but maybe this control allows adding them?

Comment: I expect so, TVST is extrememly flexible.  Somewhere (author's website?) there is a gallery of the wide range of applications and appearance that people have used it for.

Comment: I have looked through its features, looks like filter editors in the header can be done only using other controls placed in or above the header.